# How to obtain extension properties by Kotlin reflection?

Tags: kotlin, reflection, properties

I have used the `memberExtensionProperties()` method, but result collection of the extension properties is empty. The test code is attached. What is the right procedure?

```kotlin
class ExtensionPropertyTest {
    class DummyClass{}
    val DummyClass.id get() = 99
    val DummyClass.name get() = "Joe"

    @Test
    fun testExtensionProperties() {
        val dummyClass = DummyClass()
        expect(dummyClass.id).toEqual(99) // OK

        val properties = DummyClass::class.memberExtensionProperties
            .stream()
            .toList()
        expect(properties).toHaveSize(2) // Fails due a zero size
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to do that, as the extension properties can live anywhere.  I would expect the class with `memberExtensionProperties` to be `ExtensionPropertyTest`.

Answer (score 2):

`memberExtensionProperties` does not return extensions over a class, but its members that are at the same time extensions:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    println(DummyClass::class.memberExtensionProperties)
}

class DummyClass {
    val String.foo: Int
        get() = toInt()
}
```

It is not that easy if at all possible to find all extensions over a class, because extensions are detached from their receivers and they can be located anywhere in the classpath.